# change dynamically Grid Lines of grid view using asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Here I am Adding a Dynamic Grid View,here how to change GridLines of Grid View Dynamically using Asp.Net C#.
Thanks...

```
myGrid.DataSource = dt;
myGrid.DataBind();
 myGrid.GridLines = "Vertical";   // Here Not Working
 myGrid.Width = 1000;
```

Output :

```
__________________________________________________________________
Location                 Category                   Total
_________________________________________________________________
   a                     Cat1                          2
_________________________________________________________________
   b                      Cat2                         4
_________________________________________________________________
   c                     Cat3                          3
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: In grid View i want display Vertical Lines

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify CssClass in GridView and based on that it will be applied.

[See Example](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Set-GridLines-color-in-GridView-in-ASPNet.aspx)